# Subdomain wildcard for development server under dev

Tags: dns, subdomain, multiple-domains, cname

I recently purchased a new domain i.e. `mydomain.io` which I'm planning to use for my brand new app.

The app was designed to be **multi-tenant** meaning that each user account points to a different subdomain: `i.e. a.mydomain.io, b.mydomain.io` etc.

Earlier on I successfully set this up in namecheap using the following entries:

```
A Record: @ -> PRODUCTION_SERVER_IP
CNAME:    * -> mydomain.io
```

The problem now is that I also need to use a development server which complicates matters a bit.

The end goal needs to be this:

`dev.mydomain.io` and `*.dev.mydomain.io` should point to the development server at `DEVELOPMENT_SERVER_IP`.

`*.mydomain.io` and `mydomain.io` should point to the production server at `PRODUCTION_SERVER_IP`.

How should I set this up in the configuration of Namecheap?

Assume that the server configuration part has been taken care of.

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds to me like you have it all worked out already.   I'm not sure exactly what you are asking.  Do you just need to know how to use the Namecheap DNS interface?   They have some instructions https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/597/2237/how-can-i-set-up-a-catchall-wildcard-subdomain